# How can i prove that the activation link sent to subscriber (anonymous user) has actually been activated?

Tags: emails, notifications

Where can i find a log entry or related information documenting that the activation link in the confirmation mail sent to simplenews-subscribers has been activated?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Status of your subscribers by going to People > Newsletter subscriptions (`/admin/people/simplenews`).

---

There are 4 places within Drupal admin navigation that Simplenews entries are interspersed into:

- Configuration » Web services » Newsletters (`/admin/config/services/simplenews`) for **creating different Newsletters** (you want at least one)
- Structure » Content types » Simplenews newsletter (`/admin/structure/types/manage/simplenews`) to choose and edit a **Content type to use for the newsletter content**
- People » Newsletter subscriptions (`/admin/people/simplenews`) to list and filter all **your Subscribers**
- Content » Newsletters (`/admin/content/simplenews`) to see all the created **Newsletter issues** and their status